# What is stub in ejb?

Tags: ejb, stub

What is a stub in ejb?
Is it a reference variable for Remote Bean class Object in remote JVM or it is a reference variable for Object residing in the same JVM?

Comment: have stubs been deprecated?  if so, to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is a reference variable to an Object residing in the same JVM.

The key point is that this object has the ability to communicate with a remote object residing in another JVM. 
It's a Proxy that encapsulates the remote method invocation details, which allows you to invoke methods in a remote object as if it was residing in the same JVM.